# How to use Loop in Jekyll

Tags: rubygems, liquid, jekyll

Suppose I have a directory and file structure as shown below in the jekyll for creating the static site. In this case how can I make a loop for the dev directory so that each time i can get the content of the *.md file

```
static-site
       |
        content
         |
        dev
         |
          test1.md
          test2.md
          text3.md
```

Comment: What are you looking to do with the content you get from the dev/*.md files? Do you just want to output HTML files, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

locate your *.md content in your _posts folder (sub dir is fine) and then call your content with something like:

```
{% for post in site.categories.dev %}

{{ post.content }}

{% endfor %}
```

be sure to include the "dev" category to your yaml front matter.